# what is the record for a team being awarded a penalty in consecutive soccer matches?

Tags: football, history, officiating, trivia, records

What is the record for a team being awarded a penalty in consecutive soccer matches?

Leicester City FC currently have 5 in a row, all being converted by the same person, and have 8 for the season.

Comment: I think the record you gave there could be the answer. I asked the question on the Guardian knowledge section and no one could give me an answer. So five awarded in a row could be the answer.

Comment: Should be in different games?? according to a newpaper in argentina (the newspaper is a good one) we have a team with 6 penalties in 5 matches, and the record is holded by another team with 7 penalties (I'm trying to look for in how many games)

Comment: @gbianchi bear in mind that "6 in 5 matches" does not imply they were consecutive: there might still be a match without penalties in the middle.

Comment: @Lohoris They were in consecutives matches.. http://mundod.lavoz.com.ar/futbol/talleres-y-una-racha-historica-con-sus-penales link is in spanish...

Comment: @gbianchi So 6 in 5 matches seems to be the record? You should put it as the answer below if it seems legitimate

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://mundod.lavoz.com.ar/futbol/talleres-y-una-racha-historica-con-sus-penales) on line newspaper (that has his corresponding real version), the record is holded by a team with 7 penalties (but it doesn't said in how many matches).

But it has info about this team, Talleres de cordoba, who in 1952 has 6 penalties in 5 consecutives matches.